# How to request something in subdomain api.foo.com from client.foo.com without CORS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I have a project with multiple services most of them on the same domain but on different subdomains, like

client.foo.com 
api.foo.com

I have a task to get the client do a direct/plain ajax requests to the API without using CORS, is it possible?

thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Why not use CORS? That's what it's made for.

Comment: That's what I think, but that's the task requirement